Is it possible to programmatically select folders in a library from displaying or not in OneDrive
Good Afternoon,
Does anyone know if it's programmatically possible to develop a script where it would be able to turn 'on' or 'off' (to make visible or not) the folders in a user's OneDrive sync from a SharePoint Library?
As shown here:

I suspect that the only language capable of doing it would be PowerShell (certainly could be wrong though).
Thanks for everyone's time and effort, Peace,
